Shutdown android programmatically
I am creating an android app in java. My app is a device admin and works in kiosk mode.
I wish to create a battery protector that will automatically turn off the device if no charging and battery level is below certain level.
I am looking for a solution to shutdown the device programmatically. There are functions in DevicePolicyManager and PowerManager for reboot but none for shutdown. Device is non root so calling an adb command programmatically is also not allowed.

Some of the answers on the linked question suggest an API, but note that you can't unless you're signed with the system key.  I can't independently verify that, say, a device admin in kiosk mode can't call that, though, so...maybe that's worth a try?
